# Password Protecting App in Development (Codeigniter)

Tags: security, .htaccess, codeigniter

I am developing a web application using CI at www.example.com . My CI install is located outside the www root folder.

How do I go about password protecting my application while still allowing
my "home page" (in this case the default controller/view in CI ) to be
publicly accessible ?

I.E. I want to develop my application without any authorized users (i.e.
the public) poking around, but still want a landing page to be visible.

I've been able to use .htaccess to password protect my entire www root, is
there anyway to exclude the home page from protection ? And if so, what
file would I exclude in my CI setup ?

Any ideas on how this is accomplished on a generic (non codeigniter) website / web application would also be appreciated

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. If your ci installation is outside the www root then why do you need to password protect it? I'm assuming you've got it working by pointing you index.php file to the correct application path? Also, why have you password protected the entire web root? Surely the point of that destination is to allow remote users to access the files. Could you clarify exactly what it is you're trying to achieve? Apolgies if I've misunderstood.

Comment: did the following answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

To exclude specific pages from being password protected, for example page.html you would add the following to your .htaccess file:

```
<Files "page.html">
  Allow from all
  Satisfy any
</Files>
```

You can see examples of how to do this, as well as how to exclude multiple files [here](http://brett.batie.com/software-development/password-protect-all-but-one-file-htaccess/).